# Code works in console, but not in head

Tags: jquery

When I enter this script in the Google Chrome console...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("div").hover(
            function() { $("> span", this).show(); },
            function() { $("> span", this).hide(); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

... it works and no problem.

When I add this between `<head></head>` it does not work.

Can anyone tell me why?

**UPDATE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
     <script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $('div').hover(function()
    {
        $('> span', this).show();
    }, function()
    {
        $('> span', this).hide();
    });
});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">

    $.getJSON("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.json?callback=?&count=5", function(data) {

  $.each(data, function(index, value) { 
 $('.tweets').append('<div id='+data[index].id+'>'+data[index].text+'&nbsp<span style="display:none"class="hideTweeterIcons"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to='+data[index].id+'"><img src="//si0.twimg.com/images/dev/cms/intents/icons/reply.png"></a><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id='+data[index].id+'"><img src="//si0.twimg.com/images/dev/cms/intents/icons/retweet.png"></a><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id='+data[index].id+'"><img src="https://si0.twimg.com/images/dev/cms/intents/icons/favorite.png"></a></span></div><hr>');

});     
});

    </script>
```

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ with what you currently have, including any HTML, JS and CSS required.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've provided is using the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/), be sure you're including references to the libraries before using the jQuery `$` function. Additionally, try specifying the `type` on the script tag, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
</script>
```

### Update

After revising your code, I noticed that the `hover` functionality is set-up incorrectly, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('div').hover(function()
    {
        $('> span', this).show();
    }, function()
    {
        $('> span', this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: yeap.My jquery library is defined before this script. I did what you advise, but same there's nochange :S

Comment: Your `hover` function was wrong. I've updated my answer to fix this.

Comment: oops, silly mistake, try now. Are you able to post more of your source code?

Comment: your code is working on Firefox but not on Chrome . I really dont know what the wrong is . I shared more code

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure jQuery code is AFTER you've added in the jQuery library. If you're using the HTML5 boilerplate, this occurs at the bottom of the page.